# Using multiple dataset for =iif(isNothing(First(Fields!field.Value

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, expression

I have the below expression but want to add additional datasets into the existing expression for validation.

Existing expression:

```
=iif(isNothing(First(Fields!ordnum.Value, "FirstDataset")) = True, "No","Yes")
```

I would like to do something like the below in which if any data is present within any of the datasets, the result returns Yes, otherwise, No

```
=iif(isNothing(First(Fields!ordnum.Value, "FirstDataset"),(Fields!ordnum.Value, "SecondDataset"),(Fields!ordnum.Value, "ThirdDataset") ) = True, "No","Yes")
```

Something else I tried is but get the following error: **The Value expression for the textrun ‘ordnum_1.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30516] Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments.**

```
=iif(isNothing(First(Fields!ordnum.Value, "FirstDataset")) = True, "No","Yes", iif(isNothing(First(Fields!ordnum.Value, "SecondDataset")) = True, "No","Yes"), iif(isNothing(First(Fields!ordnum.Value, "ThirdDataset")) = True, "No","Yes"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an OR in the IIF to check for any one of multiple conditions.

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(First(Fields!ordnum.Value, "FirstDataset")) OR
    ISNOTHING(First(Fields!ordnum.Value, "SecondDataset")) OR 
    ISNOTHING(First(Fields!ordnum.Value, "ThirdDataset")), "No","Yes")
```

Comment: @dnk - your expression is set to show NO if any exists. `IIF ... = True, [THEN] "No", [ELSE]"Yes")` Do you need to switch the NO and YES?

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and it returned "No" as a result even though the data did exist in SecondDataset.

I also tried adding "True" towards the end of the expresssion but still ended up with the same unwanted result


=IIF(ISNOTHING(First(Fields!ordnum.Value, "FirstDataset")) OR
    ISNOTHING(First(Fields!ordnum.Value, "SecondDataset")) OR 
    ISNOTHING(First(Fields!ordnum.Value, "ThirdDataset"))=True, "No","Yes")

Comment: good idea @Hannover Fist, this however resulted in "Yes" being the answer. However, when testing it with other data that don't exist in any Datasets, it still returned "Yes" as the answer. 

I also tried limiting it down to 2 datasets only or switching the order, SecondDataset and FirstDataset using the original set up but they all ended up being "No" as the answer.

Comment: @dnk - maybe that ISNOTHING doesn't work as expected on an empty dataset. Maybe use CountRows `=IIF(CountRows("FirstDataset") > 0 OR blah blah ..., "No","Yes")`

Comment: no success :(
I tried using only one dataset where I knew the data exist which returned No. I also tried to specify =IIF (CountRows(Fields!ordnum.Value, "SecondDataset") > 0, "No","Yes") but got an error: The Value expression for the textrun ‘ordnum_1.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset.
Using ISNOTHING seemed to be working when using one Dataset

Comment: I can't see why Hannover's answer would not work. I suggest you temporarily add some extra columns for debugging and set the expression of each column to a single dataset e.g. `=ISNOTHING(First(Fields!ordum.Value "FirstDataset")` or `=COUNTROWS("FirstDataset")` and make sure you are getting the results you expected before trying to combine them into one expression.

Comment: @HannoverFist, I was able to get your CountRows suggestion to work. I must have fat fingered the values when entering the data using your original example, 
=IIF(CountRows("FirstDataset") > 0 OR blah blah, "No","Yes")